# Selenium webdriver: I was able click on a textbox but not able to send any text through sendKeys. for example email id textbox

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am not able to pass value in a text box through sendkeys() in selenium Webdriver(Java). But we can enter manually. I tried every thing xpath, cssSelector, id. Any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say: "I tried every thing", please share your code and share the html you are targeting. And when you say "I am not able to pass value in a text box", what exactly happens. Without the details there is no way of telling what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post code the code snippet and html source file.

Folowing can be reason :

1. The element you are tring to access can be in a frame.
   In that case use `driver.switchTo.frame("frame_name");`
2. Check for browser settings in tools---> Internet options --> Security tab--> All the levels of security should be protected or non-protected.
3. Check if there is java vm plugin in your browser.
4. Check if browser zoom level is 100%. It affects mouse click

Comment: @ Abhishek
Following is the html code:
<div class="mvs">
<input class="sharebar_share_link" type="text" readonly="true" name="share_link" data-behavior="select_text_when_clicked"/>
</div>
 I am trying to get the text displayed in the textbox but it is not happening..

Comment: readonly = 'true' so you cannot enter text using sendKeys()

Comment: to get the text use   

String text = driver.findElement(By.name("share_link")).getAttribute("value");

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Following is the code where i want to enter text ... (it's a email id textbox)...
<div class="input full_width_input selector_input_box"> // When i inspect the element....

Comment: // Inside it
<div class="input full_width_input selector_input_box">
<ul class="inline_list mbn mtn">
<li class="pan badge_selector_input_item">
</ul>
</div>

Comment: Please paste the entire html code here !

Comment: Yeah sure 
Following is the entire code
<div class="line split_column">
<div class="unit control size1of1">
<div id="contacts_selector_list" class="option_selector" style="display: block; position: relative; z-index: 3;">
<div class="input full_width_input selector_input_box">
<div class="drop_down_container mtn" style="display: none;">
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Ask a seperate question for that please. We cannot continue discussing it here. This is in accordance to stack overflow guidelines !